# Java 8 stream sum and count at once

Tags: java, java-stream, average

How can I use Java 8 streams to calculate an average of the stream elements? 
Because I cannot use a stream twice I have to do it in one iteration. 
The stream contains custom beans holding a float value. The number of elements in the stream may vary.
Hence, I want to sum up the float value of all elements in the stream and divide it by the number of elements in the stream.

**Update:**
Finally I need the sum of all elements in the stream as well a the average of all elemnts of the stream.

Comment: 1) `reduce` is a general method of iteration, it can do anything a loop can do. In particular, the accumulator can be as complex as you want it to be. For example, you could use an accumulator with is a pair of `(index, sum)` and in the end just divide `sum` by `index`. 2) Actually, average can be computed online without having to know the size of the stream and in fact even for infinite streams: the average at each point of the computation is "new average = old average + (next data - old average) / next count".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your `Stream` to a `DoubleStream` and call `average()` to calculate the average:

```
OptionalDouble average = yourStream.mapToDouble(YourStreamElementClass::getFloatValue).average();
```

If you want additional statistics (such as max value, min value, number of elements, etc...), you can call `summaryStatistics()` instead of `average()`.